# Back button on android device is not working

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

In unity2017 I'm trying to use android device's back button to go to scene 1. Here is my code:

```
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape)){
    SceneManager.LoadScene(1);
}
```

This code is not working, I tested it unity editor as well as after building apk on device.
Anyone have idea how to make it work?

Comment: Can you print anything inside the statement and also outside? Inside will tell you if the call works/fails, outside will tell you if you forgot to attach the script on a game object.

Comment: The snippet seems correct, it's probably not the issue.

Comment: Can you provide some context. For example where do you have this if statement placed?

Comment: Yes i debugged and if statement is executed. If statement is in update function and Script is attached to a gameobject which is controlling game.

Comment: Have you tried Input.GetKeyDown instead of Input.GetKey ?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with `if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Escape))` in Unity and it should execute as long as that code is placed in the `Update` function.

In order for the Update function to be called, the folliwing must be true:

**1**. The script it is inside is enabled

**2**. The GameObject that script is attached to is active and is not destroyed with [`Destroy`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.Destroy.html) function.

If the above are already true then *possible problem is that you did **not** add the scene to the Build Settings.*

You need to add the scenes to the *Build Settings*, otherwise `SceneManager.LoadScene(1);` won't work.

Note that `SceneManager.LoadScene(1);` means that it will load scene with *index 1*. This means that you must have two scenes for *index 1* to be valid since index starts from *0* not *1*. If you have one scene, use `SceneManager.LoadScene(0);` or load the scene by name `SceneManager.LoadScene("Name of Scene");` but make sure they are added to the *Build Settings*.

Below is how to add scenes to the Build Settings.

[image]

Comment: I rechecked and all things mentioned above are correct in my case, Scene is in build settings, Game object is active script is attached is working, if statment is in update function. But still on pressing back button on android device it is not going to that scene.

Comment: Doesn't make sense. 1.Are you using any plugin? 2.What happens when you remove `SceneManager.LoadScene(1);` and simply replace that a `Text` component that you update when you press the back button? Is the Text component being updated? Please answer these questions